# A girl with magical power in a different world

Tags: story-identification, magic

I read a book quite a while back (probably quite a few years ago) that I downloaded (probably for free, but maybe not) on iBooks. I do not have iTunes anymore so I can't find it from there.

It was a fantasy book about a girl with magical ability. It was set in a different world to ours. Kind of medieval-esque? It starts with her in this keep, and she works there since her mother died. There are creepy guys there but she used her magic to hurt one and now they stay away. Then this man comes along, realises she can do magic, and takes her away and trains her. There is a big plot about saving the world I think. And there's a warm hot country where there is a man called something like Soluman.

That's all I can remember. If anyone knows or thinks they know what this is, could you please tell me? I know this is very vague, but it's all I can pin down. I'm pretty sure this was part of a trilogy or series of books. And I think it had a female author.

Comment: was there some kind of music magic involved?

Comment: That sounds familiar!

Comment: Are you reasonably sure that it was Soluman (as opposed to the much more common spelling; Solomon)?

Comment: I think it was spelt differently and that's why it stuck with me.

Comment: What magic can she do to hurt people? Where does the man take her? DO you remember anything about the girl (age, name, description), was it 'Young Adult Fantasy' or was there sex in the book? Did she do spells by singing, wands, charms, crystals or runes?

Comment: From what I remember she starts off in her sort of early teens (like 13?) and then gets older as the books progress. I think there may have been a few very brief sex scenes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The series I was looking for was the [Books of Pellinor series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/49587-the-books-of-pellinor) by Alison Croggon.

I eventually found it halfway down a reddit thread on fantasy books with a female protagonists.

> Hem is a weary orphan whose struggle for survival ends when he is
> reunited with his lost sister, Maerad. But Maerad has a destiny to
> fulfill, and Hem is sent to the golden city of Turbansk, where he
> learns the ways of the Bards and befriends a mysterious white crow.
> When the forces of the Dark threaten, **Hem flees with his protector,
> Saliman,** and an orphan girl named Zelika to join the Light’s
> resistance forces. It is there that Hem has a vision and learns that
> he, too, has a part to play in Maerad’s quest to solve the Riddle of
> the Treesong.

[image: Cover of "The Naming" by Alison Croggon, captioned "The First Book of Pellinor." The cover depicts the head and shoulders of a young person with long, loose, dark brown hair, wearing a green shirt, looking to the right against a sky and clouds]

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like it could be the [Magicians Guild](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Magician_%28novel_series%29) by Judy Canavan:

> *"The Black Magician trilogy is a fantasy novel series by Australian author Trudi Canavan. The books follow a slum-dwelling girl named
> Sonea who, although born and raised in the slums of Imardin, discovers
> that she has natural magical abilities usually restricted to the upper
> classes. They describe her attempts to escape capture by the
> Magicians' Guild and gain control of her powers, her struggle to fit
> in and learn magic, and ultimately her attempts save Kyralia using the
> one type of magic forbidden from use. "*

Comment: Is there a character named Soluman (or something similar)?

Comment: No, that isn't the series I was thinking of, I have read it before. Thank you though!